# duda al pasar un parametro preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

tengo una duda quiero pasar un parámetro dentro de la regla 
ej el valor que se ingrese es 1500-2000
y quiero que únicamente valida el valor numérico con el guion entre medio. 
me falta algo aun para detectar el guion.

CODIGO:

```
if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',"1500-2000")){
echo "filtro precio";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes modificar tu expresión regular para el nuevo patrón.

Podrías utilizar `/^[0-9]+\-[0-9]+$/` para incluir el guión medio y el nuevo grupo de números.

```
if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+\-[0-9]+$/',"1500-2000")){
    echo "filtro precio";
}
```